# Wiring a pair of switchs to always on

Tags: electrical, switch, multiway-switch, smart-switch

I have 2 switches (UK) that both turn on/off a single bulb.

I'm trying to connect both switches so the power is always on.

Each **1 gang switch** has:

Common on the top
L1 / L2 on the bottom (separate) terminals

If I join Common to L1/L2 together on the same connector and repeat on the other light switch am I correct in thinking the light will always be on?

---

FYI my use case is to install 1 smart switch (requires always on power) and blank off the 2nd switch.

Comment: There are different ways to wire 3-way switches.  You should replace one switch with your Smart one, replace the other with a blank cover plate, and you *will* be able to wire it up so your new switch works but the exact details depend on exactly how things are wired now.

Comment: This may depend on the age of the house… Traditional UK lighting wiring is not conducive to replacing with a smart switch. You will have to get into the ceiling rose & drop a new neutral. The trad drop to the switch is live/switched live only, whether it's one or two-way. if you gang Com to L1 & L2 then your circuit will be permanently closed [i.e. ON]… but you'll still have no neutral which the smart switch will require. New builds *may* have been done the 'US' way with power up from the floor rather than down from the ceiling. You need to determine which it is before going any further.

Answer (score 1):

The "common" method of using two switches is like this:
[image]

Use a multimeter to test to find which wire is which, then you can connect to make it one switch only.